# Updated Wordpress and my smooth scroll stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I just updated to WordPress 4.5 and in every site I did so my smooth scroll script stopped working. It used to scroll to the appropriate container when clicking links which include #. I assume that something I use has been deprecated or changed in a new version of jQuery, but I haven't been able to find the answer.

[This is one of the sites.](https://casanola.com)

This is my code, which worked fine until today. I am using jQuery easing plugin:

```
jQuery("a[href^=#]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target_block = jQuery(this).attr("href");
        var target_scroll = jQuery(target_block).offset().top - 100;    
        var window_width = jQuery(window).width(); //retrieve current window width

        if (window_width < 760) {
      target_scroll = target_scroll + 100;
        if (jQuery(window).height() > 560) {
        target_scroll = target_scroll - 60;//compansate for mobile fixed menu
        jQuery("#site-navigation.main-navigation" ).hide(195);//Hide nav
      }
    };
            jQuery("html,body").animate({scrollTop: target_scroll}, 400, 'easeInOutQuart');
    });
```

Comment: You have an error in console:

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href^=#].

Escape your # char and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thank you Korgrue and Mukesh. I wonder then why it worked all this time, did jQuery get more strict with these kind of errors in a recent update?

Comment: It more likely has to do with a change in the way WP parses the url strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just visit your side, there is an error in your console,
'Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href^=#]'

So, here your selector is not valid. # is a special char and needs to be escaped like

```
jQuery("a[href*=\\#]").click(function(e){
```

Try this changing above line.